# Инициализация по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Если у меня в `.h` в конструкторе происходит инициализация переменных по умолчанию, то нужно ли их инициализировать снова в `.cpp` файле?
Например:

```
// .h файл
class A
{
   A(int _r = 1, int _m = 2);
   int r, m;
};
// .cpp файл
A::A(int _r, int _m):r(_r),m(_m) // нужна ли инициализация _r и _m ?
{
}
```

Или лучше вообще сделать наоборот: инициализацию в `.cpp`, а в `.h` не надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аргументы по умолчанию должны быть заданы в только прототипе функции. При этом, если опускается какой-то параметр, то все те, что правее от него, также должны быть опущены.

Comment: Т.е. в `.h` файле нужно написать `A(int = 1, int = 2);` ?

Comment: @btws да. И верно, что названия при объявлении тоже можно опускать.