# 1>D:\Projects\cpp\art\art\Source.cpp(11,18): error C2572: foo: переопределение аргумента по умолчанию: параметр 1

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
/*libs*/
#include <iostream>

/*usings*/
using namespace std;

/*proto*/
void foo(int a = 10);

/*functions*/
void foo(int a = 10)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        cout << "@" << endl;
    }
}

/*main*/
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    foo();
}
```

Comment: извиняюсь, вопрос: Почему возникает ошибка? что нужно переделать? в туторе было так же

Comment: пока только разбираюсь в прототипах, без него работает

Comment: Вы сначала в прототипе объявляете `a`, а потом в самой функции делаете то же самое. Переменная должна объявляться один раз

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Инициализация по умолчанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516254/%d0%98%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел решение!

необходимо просто удалить в прототипе значение a, достаточно просто обьявить ее
`

```
/*libs*/
#include <iostream>

/*usings*/
using namespace std;

/*proto*/
void foo(int a);

/*functions*/
void foo(int a = 10)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        cout << "@" << endl;
    }
}

/*main*/
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    foo();
}
```

`